# How to change variables in a subroutine from another

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to change `array` and `array2` within `main()` with values from a subroutine (called `change()`). My code:

```
def change(array,array2):

    array = "heyo"
    array2 = "7"
    return array,array2

def main():

    array = ["hello","Hey","HI"]
    array2 = ["1","2","3"]
    change(array,array2)
    print(array,array2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the return values to variables

```
def change(array,array2):
    array = "heyo"
    array2 = "7"
    return array,array2

def main():
    array, array2 = change(array,array2)
    print(array,array2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```